# Is this samsung memory ECC or not

Tags: memory, ddr3, ecc

i have question about memory name, everywhere in shops, i could find module like this:
[https://www.amazon.com/Samsung-1866MHzCL13-RegECC-Internal-M393B2G70DB0-CMA/dp/B00T3CJ6OW](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T3CJ6OW)

You could see in name "... ECC..." But when i check it in samsung site:
https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M393B2G70DB0-CMA/
Nothing about ECC there in futers. So is it ECC memory or not? And how to check it before buying?

Comment: The real question you should be asking is if the module you are asking about is even supported by your current hardware.  Your motherboard must specifically support Registered DDR3 modules.

Comment: It is not a question, supermicro have really good manual documentation with detailed description. And even list of tested supported hardware for every MB.
For samsung i did check Datasheet and didnt find any ecc there, and somehow miss "SPD" docs where it is described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You could see in name "... ECC..." But when i check it in samsung site:

Amazon does not actually curate product descriptions unless an error is reported to them.  This is specifically the case when the product is only sold by a third-party.  The memory module in question, has two different part numbers assosiated with it, [M393B2G70DB0-CK002/CMA02](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/spd/M393B2G70DB0-CK002_CMA02-0.pdf) and [M393B2G70DB0-CK003/CMA03](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/spd/M393B2G70DB0-CK003_CMA03-0.pdf).  Based on the specifications, provided by Samsung, both of those part numbers are registered DDR3 ECC modules.

> So is it ECC memory or not? And how to check it before buying?

The Amazon page does not specifiy the full part number.  So it is not possible to determine if the modules the third-party is selling has one of those part numbers.  However, based on Samsung's own documentation, it appears that [M393B2G70DB0-CMA](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M393B2G70DB0-CMA/) is indeed ECC Registered DDR3 memory.

**If you have any doubts about the item the third-party is selling you should contact them directly.**